# using terraform or aws cli how to enable/tick "Enable load balancing" when creating an application (codedeploy)

Tags: terraform, aws-cli

In AWS when creating a Codedeploy/application, how to enable the "Enable load balancing" option using the awscli or terraform?

Using the command line I can only select/define the target group but the "Enable load balancing" remains disabled

```
aws deploy update-deployment-group --application-name app_test --current-deployment-group-name app_test --load-balancer-info targetGroupInfoList=[{name=test}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `--deployment-style` full command:

```
aws deploy update-deployment-group --application-name app_test --current-deployment-group-name app_test --load-balancer-info targetGroupInfoList=[{name=test}] --deployment-style deploymentType=IN_PLACE,deploymentOption=WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL
```

Notice `WITH_TRAFIC_CONTROL`:

```
 --deployment-style deploymentType=IN_PLACE,deploymentOption=WITH_TRAFFIC_CONTROL
```